# How to add new attribute to Struts 1 <s:form>?

Tags: javascript, struts, struts-1

This is document from Zurb abide validation tool:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html#setting-up-validation

I use Struts 1 form, and try something like this:

```
<s:form styleId="frmAddEstate" action="${addEstateProfile}" data-abide>
    // input fields...
</s:form>
```

but not working.
Please help me put `"data-abide"` to form tag. (I think we will revise file `*.tld` - tag lib definition).

Comment: Use plain `form` tag or if your tag supports dynamic attributes you can try `data-abide="true"`.

Comment: I tried plain `form` tag, but inside `form` tag, I have many fields: `<s:text>`, `<s:textarea>`, etc, then error happen.

Comment: Which Struts are you using? You say S1 but tags are from S2 beside `styleId` attribute.

Comment: I use an customized Struts framework. In jar file library, I see `struts-core-1.3.10.jar`, `struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar`, `struts-tiles-1.3.10.jar`. I also have `styleId` attributes in almost textbox or textarea input element.

Comment: Then customize it more to allow such attribute.

Comment: Change the TLD to allow dynamic attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to add attributes to the form when it has been loaded.

```js
document.getElementById("frmAddEstate").onload = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  var att = document.createAttribute("data-abide");
  document.getElementById("frmAddEstate").setAttributeNode(att);
}
```